# How to properly add DNS record to a route53 domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-route53

I'm trying to add the following to an aws route53 domain:

```
Type: A, host:@, pointsTo:ip address, ttl:number
```

But the template that is provided for updateDomainNameservers API is:

```
var params = {
  DomainName: 'STRING_VALUE',
  Nameservers: [ 
      Name: 'STRING_VALUE', 
      GlueIps: [
        'STRING_VALUE',
      ]
    },
  ],
  FIAuthKey: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
```

How my DNS record would fit into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [ChangeResourceRecordSets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeResourceRecordSets.html) for creating A records.

> Creates, changes, or deletes a resource record set, which contains
>   authoritative DNS information for a specified domain name or subdomain
>   name. For example, you can use ChangeResourceRecordSets to create a
>   resource record set that routes traffic for test.example.com to a web
>   server that has an IP address of 192.0.2.44.

Comment: Thanks @Sunharsan for the answer. I'm trying that starting with creating a new  hostedZone. But now getting another error that my alias target doesn't lie within the target zone. Any thoughts on that? new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49472636/route-53-alias-dns-record-the-alias-target-name-does-not-lie-within-the-target